# Install external package in Google Go

Tags: go

I was trying to install external packages in GO language. I've found many external packages at http://godashboard.appspot.com/package.
I am working on windows system.

I tried this command to install go-router package.

```
goinstall go-router.googlecode.com/svn/trunk
```

This resulted in following error....

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe: === cd c:\go\src\pkg\go-router.googlecode.com\svn\trunk;
bash gomake -f- install
/cygdrive/c/go/bin/gomake: line 3: exec: make: not found
--- exit status 127
goinstall: go-router.googlecode.com/svn/trunk: install: running bash: exit status 127
```

I am unable to find out the reason for the error and the meaning of status code. I've read the goinstall command description but no luck..

Answer (score 3):

It seems `make` command is missing. Make sure it's installed and that `PATH` variable is defined correctly.